# JSF .xcss styles not getting rendered

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using JSF2 and Richfaces 4.

I've added the following to my web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>xcss</extension>
  <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

I have an test.xcss file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:template xmlns:f="http:/jsf.exadel.com/template"
   xmlns:u="http:/jsf.exadel.com/template/util"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
   <f:verbatim><![CDATA[

#content a:link[disabled]{ cursor: default;}

]]>
</f:verbatim>

<u:selector name="body">
    <u:style name="background-color" skin="generalBackgroundColor" />
    <u:style name="font-size" skin="generalSizeFont" />
    <u:style name="font-family" skin="generalFamilyFont" />
</u:selector>

</f:template>
```

I load this test.xcss via my template.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />

<f:view contentType="text/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>TEST</title>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="test.xcss" />
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
  </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Using firebug to view the content, the test.xcss is empty. Any ideas why it is not rendering the file correctly?

I suspect .xcss files are not supported in Richfaces 4, that ecss files are now used.

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming-What_are_skins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-Skinning

.xcss not supported anymore, quite a bit of code migration to do now :(